# JavaScript Array push is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, html5-canvas, queue

I cannot figure out where is the problem.

```
var history = [];
.
.
.

window.onload = function() {
.
.
.
.


            history.push({
                xCoor: mousex,
                yCoor: mousey
            });
.
.
.
.

}
```

The full code is at: [fullCode](http://pastebin.com/aDA3JsDx)

And this is the HTML part:

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <h3>Canvas Example</h3>
    <canvas id="cv" width="600px" height="400px" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
    <script src="rendering.js"></script>
    <p id="distance">Distance: </p>
</body>

</html>
```

When I started to draw I got this error:

> TypeError: history.push is not a function

Please help me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was about to make a suggestion, but then I realize that you have made history a globally scoped variable,  maybe you should call it something else as window.history is something else entirely.

```
var otherHistory = [];

window.onload = function(){
    window.otherHistory.push({
        xCoor: mousex,
        yCoor: mousey
    });
}
```